# Minecraft modding 1.7.10 setTextureName not working

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am making a new mod and my block textures work fine but my item textures dont
i need assistance on this because i just started to code java
This Is My Script:

```
package com.HaydenMod.item;

import com.HaydenMod.lib.RefStrings;

import cpw.mods.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry;
import net.minecraft.creativetab.CreativeTabs;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;

public class DiamondShard {

    public static void MainRegistery(){
        intializeItem();
        registerItem();
    }

    public static Item Dshard;

    public static void intializeItem(){
        Dshard = new Item().setUnlocalizedName("Dshard").setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabMaterials).setTextureName(RefStrings.MODID + ":Diamond_Shard").setMaxStackSize(16);

    }

    public static void registerItem(){
        GameRegistry.registerItem(Dshard, Dshard.getUnlocalizedName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Insure that your asset file and folder names match exactly.  Always best to use all lower case.  Be sure that your texture is located in the correct place, /src/assets/[MODID]/textures/items/Diamond_Shard.png

Answer (score 0):

Try

`.setTextureName(RefStrings.MODID + ":" + "Diamond_Shard")`

If it dosn't work can you attach a pastebin with the error log

Answer (score 0):

```
YourItemName= new Item().setUnlocalizedName("YourItemName").setTextureName("yourModFile:YourtextureImageNAme").setCreativeTab(TheCreativeTabYouWantToPutItIn);
```

This is what is used and it works perfectly. The `TextureName` has to be exactly the same as the `TextureName` in the source folder.

For example, my `TextureName` is `blah.png` and in my source folder. When calling it, should write it as `setTextureName("yourModFile:blah")`.